# "pod install" creates a "SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0" attribute inside Pods.project (and no Xcode 10.2.x was ever installed on that machine) Bug?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I’m part of a team developing some architectural iOS solution involving integrating private iOS frameworks.

Part of the core of this solution needs CocoaPods and right now we’re very happy about all the complex module definition we’ve created so far.

But we have isolated an issue we don’t know if it’s a feature, a bug, a known fact… We’ll describe it here with as much detail as we can, to see if someone can shed some light on it

(It will be a crossposting doubt in stackoverflow/CocoaPods github).

EDIT: Cocoapods github thread here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8876

Context:

Our architectural solution has to cover a range of versions of iOS/Swift/Xcode for it to be deployed. The last certified versions we’re dealing with are: Swift 4.0 + Xcode 10.1 + Cocoapods 1.4.0 (yes, we know Cocoapods 1.7.1 is out, but our validation process forces us to still work with 1.4.0).

Anyway, what does it all mean? It means when we’re developing our code, we need to update our internal libraries dependencies, situation which typically is resolved with a good old “pod install”.

This pod install checks all our “brother projects” repositories and it downloads whatever new internal pods it needs, and (here comes the important part), it recreates the “Pods” project (that means it recreates the Pods.project file).

This Pods.project is the big “umbrella” where all the imported frameworks will live in our big solution. If we browse this Pods.project from within Xcode we can look for the “SWIFT_VERSION” keyword. When we do this, the expected (and wanted) result for our project is “undefined”.

So far, we’ve described the expected situation we would like to be dealing with, but some weeks ago we started to notice strange things when we needed to check our solution against different (newer) versions of “Cocoapods” (and its “satellite” associated gems).

Cocoapods is a piece of our toolkit that needs to be periodically checked, so in some machines we also started to install additional cocoapods versions (1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.0 and 1.7.1) apart from our certified 1.4.0

What does it mean? Installing different Cocoapods versions also leads to additional gem installations in the background, mainly “fourflusher”, “xcodeproj”, etc...

Typically, once you have cocoapods 1.4.0 (and 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.0 and 1.7.1) you end up with things like, more than one fourflusher version installed (2.0.1, 2.2.0), more than one cocoapods version installed (logically), and more than one xcodeproj version installed (typically 1.5.6, 1.8.X and 1.9.0).

What does it all mean in the end?

Having the latest versions of all these additional cocoapods related gems installed leads to the following (undesired for us) situation:

The “pod install” action (having deleted “Pods” folder and “Podfile.lock” file beforehand) recreates a Pods.project file, but with SWIFT_VERSION attribute set to “5.0 (unsupported)”. Why?

Particularly when we had never installed Xcode 10.2.X in these machines we’re running “pod install”

Why xcodeproj decides to add this attribute (with a value of 5.0) inside Pods.project, when in the past (Xcodeproj version 1.5.6 for example), it left this as “undefined”?

NOTE: If instead of cocoapods 1.7.X we upgrade to just cocoapods 1.6.x, then xcodeproj gem will raise to version 1.8.X

The behaviour of this other xcodeproj version (1.8.X) is apparently similar to 1.9.X, but instead of adding a (we think unneeded) SWIFT_VERSION attribute with a value of 5.0, it also creates it but with a value of 4.2.

This is not a problem if you just have Xcode 10.1 installed, as this version of Xcode DOES understand how to deal with Swift 4.2, or at least, it offers you to upgrade your project settings.

Our actual question is: is all this a known situation? why does cocoapods/Xcodeproj 1.8.X /1.9.0 decide to raise the SWIFT_VERSION to 4.2/5.0

(especially in the 5.0 case, where Xcode 10.2.(x) had never been installed on those machines)

Just in case someone might think some sibling-project might have an internal SWIFT_VERSION setting of 5.0 already set, (and this might be the reason for this value to get propagated to the Pods.project file), we have to say that no subproject/framework has SWIFT_VERSION set to 5.0

Why we know this? Because we run this command in the root of our big solution folder

```
grep “SWIFT_VERSION = 5\.0” * -r
```

and it never finds any 5.0 instance.

Besides, inside of each private framework pod, we've manually set to 4.0 the s.swift_version attribute.

Any hints about why "pod install" seems to trigger an (unwanted) SWIFT_VERSION 5.0 inside the Pods.project file, even though we never had any Xcode 10.2.x installed on it?
Is it a bug? feature? known situation? expectable situation?

Comment: _our validation process forces us to still work with 1.4.0_ ... change your validation process? As a bare minimum, anyone should use cocoapods '~> 1.6', fourflusher '~> 2.3', xcodeproj '~> 1.9' ... that is, with semantic versioning for using latest non-breaking stable releases.

Comment: Also, as having even shipped apps using custom forks of cocoapods / fourflusher / xcodeproj, I advice the usage of `bundler` and a GemFile in your process. In the GemFile, you may hardcode `gem 'xcodeproj', '1.8.2'; gem 'cocoapods', '1.4.0'` and you can now freely use `bundle exec pod install` without risking the wrong version of xcodeproj being used.

Comment: @Cœur It's precisely the homologation process for 1.6.0 and 1.7.0 the one that triggered this strange and somewhat unwanted behaviour. It's our client the one deciding the Cocoapods version we should use. We also want to use 1.6.0 but we think we detected this weird issue and we want to confirm if it's a bug/feature/something else. Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, previous Swift version handling in CocoaPods has been obsoleted by the newer handling in 1.7.x, so it's not worth trying to debug it in older versions. [I even wrote some time ago that podspecs made for CocoaPods 1.7.0 would break support for 1.6.x.](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8191#issuecomment-463877566). You could say that the podspec format for 1.7.0 should have been released as a 2.0.0 version, and/or made available by sharding the specs repo. That may be unrelated to your issue, but it demonstrates that there is **no more support for 1.6.x**.

Comment: So just say "_sorry_" to your client and ask them to override the Swift version by themself in their Podfile, with a post_install hook like: `post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
        t.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
        end
    end
end`

Comment: last note: the project is generated by `xcodeproj`, not by `cocoapods` itself, that's why I wrote `gem 'xcodeproj', '1.8.2'` above: your issue may be with it instead of being with cocoapods. [ edit: [that's confirmed in this comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8876#issuecomment-500529555) ]

Comment: Yes, we know our client should be using 1.6.0 or 1.7.0, but we're precisely validating these cocoapods versions, and specially their related gems, (i.e. xcodeproj), behave as expected or wanted. Our client can't still use XCode 10.2 as of today, because many parts of its codebase is still in Swift 3. ALL projects show a proper SWIFT_VERSION (<= 4.2 or inexistant),  it's the Pods.project file the one that seems to be pushing against 5.0 if xcodeproj 1.9 is in charge of creating it, even Xcode 10.2 is not installed on our machines. We want to know if it's a bug or a feature. We'll test 'bundle'.